# Kinect: Convert Joint.Position.Z in millimeters

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I know how to convert in pixels the value obtained from `Joint.Position.X` and `Joint.Position.Y`. There is an example in which I do it:

```
void kinectSensor_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (skeletonFrame != null)
            {
                Skeleton[] skeletonData = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength]; //conterrà tutti gli skeleton

                skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletonData);

                Skeleton playerSkeleton = (from s in skeletonData where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked select s).FirstOrDefault();

                if (playerSkeleton != null)
                {
                    Joint rightHand = playerSkeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
                    Joint leftHand = playerSkeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];

                    //EDIT: The following formulas used to convert X and Y coordinates in pixels are wrong.
                    //Please, see the answer for details
                    rightHandPosition = new float[] { (((0.5f * rightHand.Position.X) + 0.5f) * (640)), (((-0.5f * rightHand.Position.Y) + 0.5f) * (480)) };
                    leftHandPosition = new float[] { (((0.5f * leftHand.Position.X) + 0.5f) * (640)), (((-0.5f * leftHand.Position.Y) + 0.5f) * (480)), leftHand.Position.Z };
                }
             }
         }
    }
```

Now, what I want to do is obtain the real depth (in millimeters) using `Joint.Depth.Z`. Referring to the previous example, I want to obtain two 3D arrays for `rightHandPosition` and `leftHandPosition`, with the the last coordinate that represents the depth. What is the right formula in order to transform the value returned from `rightHand.Position.Z` and `leftHand.Position.Z` in the corresponding value in millimeters?

**EDIT: The formulas used to transform X and Y coordinates in pixels in the code above are wrong. Please, read the following answer by me.**

Comment: I don't know anything about how the Kinect works, but I can deduce a bit from what you've posted.  Judging from what you posted, rightHand (and leftHand).Position gives you a 3D {x,yz,} value, normalized from 0 to 1.  So, you have a 3D coordinate.  You just need to scale and maybe translate it.  What is that 0..1 range covering?  I'd assume it's the bounding box of what the Kinect scans.  Can you query that information from somewhere?  If so, just multiply each dimension times (its end point - its start point) and add the start point.

Comment: I asked this question because sometimes I receive values for Z that are greater than 1. That's the problem... But thank you for your suggestions :)

Comment: The value returned by `Position.Z` is in meters.

Comment: @Evil Closet Monkey: Can you give me a reference in which what you said is confirmed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx -- "skeleton space coordinates are expressed in meters."

Comment: Does it mean that Position.X and Position.Z are expressed in meters too?

Comment: Yup.  Looks like you found a few other sources with your self-answer below.  Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have realized that `Joint.Position.X` and `Joint.Position.Y` are not limited between -1 and 1. This wrong information is quite diffused on internet, and this is the reason why I'm replying to myself.

As [Evil Closet Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411063/evil-closet-monkey) has mentioned, in the comments above, the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx) says that "**skeleton space coordinates are expressed in meters**". It's also confirmed by a member of the Kinect for Windows Team in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/9725f685-5839-43db-b13d-aa9afcf1b7a5).

It means that in order to convert X, Y and Z coordinates, obtained with `Joint.Position.X`, `Joint.Position.Y` and `Joint.Position.Z`, in millimeters, you simply have to divide these values by 1000 (or you can also work in meters, with no conversions needed).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by earlier, positions are given in meters. Simply multiply by 1000 to convert meters in millimeters. [image: Conversion According To Google]

Comment: This should be a comment.